# How to get SIM 2 details from android device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to get the details of SIM 2 from dual SIM android device which is API level higher than 22. I want to capture following details,

```
 Sim2SubscriberId
 Sim2SimOperator
 Sim2OperatorName
 Sim2NetworkType
 Sim2NetworkOperatorName
 Sim2SerialNumber
```

How can we capture details from SubscriptionInfo. 
Please Help

Answer (score 0):

Make this class **TelephonyInfo.java** :

```
 import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

public final class TelephonyInfo {

private static TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo;
private String imeiSIM1;
private String imeiSIM2;
private boolean isSIM1Ready;
private boolean isSIM2Ready;

public String getImeiSIM1() {
    return imeiSIM1;
}

/*public static void setImeiSIM1(String imeiSIM1) {
    TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = imeiSIM1;
}*/

public String getImeiSIM2() {
    return imeiSIM2;
}

/*public static void setImeiSIM2(String imeiSIM2) {
    TelephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = imeiSIM2;
}*/

public boolean isSIM1Ready() {
    return isSIM1Ready;
}

/*public static void setSIM1Ready(boolean isSIM1Ready) {
    TelephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = isSIM1Ready;
}*/

public boolean isSIM2Ready() {
    return isSIM2Ready;
}

/*public static void setSIM2Ready(boolean isSIM2Ready) {
    TelephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = isSIM2Ready;
}*/

public boolean isDualSIM() {
    return imeiSIM2 != null;
}

private TelephonyInfo() {
}

public static TelephonyInfo getInstance(Context context){

    if(telephonyInfo == null) {

        telephonyInfo = new TelephonyInfo();

        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

        telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();;
        telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = null;

        try {
            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 0);
            telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceIdGemini", 1);
        } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

            try {
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM1 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 0);
                telephonyInfo.imeiSIM2 = getDeviceIdBySlot(context, "getDeviceId", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = telephonyManager.getSimState() == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY;
        telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = false;

        try {
            telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 0);
            telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimStateGemini", 1);
        } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

            try {
                telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 0);
                telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready = getSIMStateBySlot(context, "getSimState", 1);
            } catch (GeminiMethodNotFoundException e1) {
                //Call here for next manufacturer's predicted method name if you wish
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return telephonyInfo;
}

private static String getDeviceIdBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

    String imei = null;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try{

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimID = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        Object ob_phone = getSimID.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

        if(ob_phone != null){
            imei = ob_phone.toString();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
    }

    return imei;
}

private static  boolean getSIMStateBySlot(Context context, String predictedMethodName, int slotID) throws GeminiMethodNotFoundException {

    boolean isReady = false;

    TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

    try{

        Class<?> telephonyClass = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());

        Class<?>[] parameter = new Class[1];
        parameter[0] = int.class;
        Method getSimStateGemini = telephonyClass.getMethod(predictedMethodName, parameter);

        Object[] obParameter = new Object[1];
        obParameter[0] = slotID;
        Object ob_phone = getSimStateGemini.invoke(telephony, obParameter);

        if(ob_phone != null){
            int simState = Integer.parseInt(ob_phone.toString());
            if(simState == TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_READY){
                isReady = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new GeminiMethodNotFoundException(predictedMethodName);
    }

    return isReady;
}


private static class GeminiMethodNotFoundException extends Exception {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -996812356902545308L;

    public GeminiMethodNotFoundException(String info) {
        super(info);
    }
}
}
```

And then use this class like that:

```
private void isDualSimOrNot(){
    TelephonyInfo telephonyInfo = TelephonyInfo.getInstance(this);

    String imeiSIM1 = telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM1();
    String imeiSIM2 = telephonyInfo.getImeiSIM2();

    boolean isSIM1Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM1Ready();
    boolean isSIM2Ready = telephonyInfo.isSIM2Ready();

    boolean isDualSIM = telephonyInfo.isDualSIM();
    Log.i("Dual = "," IME1 : " + imeiSIM1 + "\n" +
            " IME2 : " + imeiSIM2 + "\n" +
            " IS DUAL SIM : " + isDualSIM + "\n" +
            " IS SIM1 READY : " + isSIM1Ready + "\n" +
            " IS SIM2 READY : " + isSIM2Ready + "\n");
}
```

Add this permission to the apps AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is only for getting device Id. I want to capture Sim2SubscriberId,
 Sim2SimOperator,
 Sim2OperatorName,
 Sim2NetworkType,
 Sim2NetworkOperatorName,
 Sim2SerialNumber.

Comment: Above code is working fine for only getting IMEI of dual SIM device.